# str.charCodeAt() not working on array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use str.charCodeAt() on a particular index on an array.
This is the code that isn't working:

```
function rot13(str) { 

  str = str.split("");

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    str[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);


  }


  return var1;
}

rot13("SERR");
```

The error is: "TypeError: str.charCodeAt() is not a function".

This works if I assign the array index to a variable and then do it on the variable, do I have to do this or is there a way to do it on the array?

With the variable it's:

```
var1 = str[i];
var1 = var1.charCodeAt();
str[i] = var1;
```

Comment: You wrote `str.charCodeAt`, not `str[i].charCodeAt`. It’s generally a good idea to avoid confusing names, like a variable called `str` that sometimes contains a string and sometimes contains an array.

Comment: why are you returning `var1` it doesn't exist in your function

Comment: You return `var1`, but never define it?

Comment: you definitely don't need to split the string into an array, `String` is an iterable object, so, just iterate on it.

Answer (score 3):

`charCodeAt()` only works on strings, not arrays. You need to access the array element. Each array element contains a string with one element, you can use `charCodeAt()` on that string.

```
str[i] = str[i].charCodeAt(0);
```

But there isn't really a need to split the string into an array in the first place. You can use a different variable for the result array.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(rot13("SERR"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more functional approach by mapping over an array of the characters that returns the charcode.

```js
const rot13 = (str) => str.split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0))

console.log(
  rot13("SERR")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have multiple problems here,

```
   str = str.split("");
```

When you do that `str` becomes an array and it is no more a `String`. That is the reason you getting the error.

All you need to do is just remove the split related code and  after minor fixes, it should work fine

```
function rot13(str) { 
  var var1=[];
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var1[i]  = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return var1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [`Array.prototype.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control), but mind that you probably don't need to split the string into an Array because String is an iterable object.

```js
function rot13(str) { 

  return Array.from(str, (char, i) => str.charCodeAt(i))
}

console.log(rot13("SERR"));
```